# Encrypting a message while writing it

Tags: python, encryption

I made a simple script in python that takes a string and encrypts it by moving every letter by random number between 1 and 10:

```
from random import randint

n = input('>>')

for i in n:
    print(chr(ord(i) + randint(1,10)), end = '')
```

so for example i write "seven" and it gives me "yh~gx". What I want to know is it possible to make this happen as you are writing the string. For example if I wanted to write "seven" it would display "yh~gx". I know this is possible in C++ but I'm not sure how to do it in python.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  And this isn't encrypting, it's just... scrambling I guess.  I don't even know what to call it.  If this is for fun, great.  If not, **abandon ship**.

Comment: @LukePark yeah it is not for any practical purpose just fun.

Comment: This has some resemblance to a Vigenere cipher, though that shifts by MOD 26, not by 10.  You are using `randint` to generate the keystream rather than a fixed repeating key.  Looking at Python implementations of the Vigenere cipher might help with some ideas.  Specifically you need to look at how you will decrypt your encrypted stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is **not** well-suited for this kind of work. Best solution I could find works only on Windows, and there is no way to exit the program but to kill the terminal window (or you can add a check for some character, if you want).

```
import msvcrt
from random import randint

while True:
    msvcrt.putch(chr((ord(msvcrt.getch()) + randint(1, 10)) % 128).encode('ascii'))
```

This solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21659588/6591347).